# java.lang.runtimeexception adding window failed android in Listview

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I have created an Android Application in that I use the ListView for displaying friend list.

So when I scroll downs, the app is crashed and the error is:

```
"java.lang.runtimeexception adding window failed android"
```

Mt code is:

```
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_alluser, null);
        holder.ivImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_propic_itemGrid);
        holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Name_itemGrid);
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) holder.ivImage.getBackground()).getBitmap();
        w = b.getWidth();
        h = b.getHeight();

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imgvwDimens = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w, h);
        holder.ivImage.setLayoutParams(imgvwDimens);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    UserDetail detail = displayList.get(position);

    aQuery.id(holder.ivImage).image(detail.getImage());
    holder.tvName.setText(detail.getName());

    return convertView;
```

Please help me for solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: you should share more details of your logcat error.

Comment: show your `ViewHolder`

Comment: class ViewHolder
 {
  ImageView ivImage;
  TextView tvName;
 }

Comment: @Fahim, I added the libraries, but still crashes with same error.